# Replace newline with literal \\n?

Tags: raku

How would I replace a newline with a literal `'\n'` in raku? I tried `s/\n/\\n/` which I expected to work but did not.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it has only worked for the first instance, since you haven't specified a global replacement. For your example code that would mean `s:g/\n/\\n/;`. However many methods of reading files into Raku auto-chomp by default, so we may need more example text/code to adequately address your issue.

Comment: It works for me. That is to say the code `$_ = "\n"; s/\n/\\n/; .say` displays `\n` using Rakudo v2022.02. As jubliatious1 says, please provide a [MRE]. Or maybe you've typo'd or gotten confused?

Comment: I can take Shakespeare's ***Sonnet 18*** , `slurp` it in to retain embedded newlines, and then create double-backslashed output with `raku -e 'put S:g/\n/\\\\n/ given slurp;' sonnet18.txt`. Is that what you want, `\\n` in the output? If so, I can write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you read Shakespeare's *[Sonnet 18](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45087/sonnet-18-shall-i-compare-thee-to-a-summers-day)* into Raku `slurp`[-wise](https://docs.raku.org/routine/slurp), (a.k.a. all at once) this is what you'll get:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'slurp.raku.put;' sonnet18.txt
"Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?\nThou art more lovely and more temperate:\nRough winds do shake the darling buds of May,\nAnd summer’s lease hath all too short a date;\nSometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,\nAnd often is his gold complexion dimm'd;\nAnd every fair from fair sometime declines,\nBy chance or nature’s changing course untrimm'd;\nBut thy eternal summer shall not fade,\nNor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st;\nNor shall death brag thou wander’st in his shade,\nWhen in eternal lines to time thou grow’st:\n   So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,\n   So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.\n"
```

Above you see embedded `\n` newlines when `slurp`ing (visualized with a call to `.raku`, giving you an idea how Raku represents objects internally).  But if you read the file in `line`[-wise](https://docs.raku.org/routine/lines), by default Raku one-liners implement newline processing identical to Perl's `-l` [command-line flag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches). Which is to say, `\n` newlines are stripped from input, and added back during output (if so desired). So this is what you'll get when reading `line`-wise:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'lines.raku.put;' sonnet18.txt
("Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?", "Thou art more lovely and more temperate:", "Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,", "And summer’s lease hath all too short a date;", "Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,", "And often is his gold complexion dimm'd;", "And every fair from fair sometime declines,", "By chance or nature’s changing course untrimm'd;", "But thy eternal summer shall not fade,", "Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st;", "Nor shall death brag thou wander’st in his shade,", "When in eternal lines to time thou grow’st:", "   So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,", "   So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.").Seq
```

Note above, `\n` newlines are removed (`chomp`ed) off of each line. A more readable output is obtained iterating via a `for` loop:

```perl
~$ raku -e '.raku.put for lines;' sonnet18.txt
"Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?"
"Thou art more lovely and more temperate:"
"Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,"
"And summer’s lease hath all too short a date;"
"Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,"
"And often is his gold complexion dimm'd;"
"And every fair from fair sometime declines,"
"By chance or nature’s changing course untrimm'd;"
"But thy eternal summer shall not fade,"
"Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st;"
"Nor shall death brag thou wander’st in his shade,"
"When in eternal lines to time thou grow’st:"
"   So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,"
"   So long lives this, and this gives life to thee."
```

Which is same as dropping `for lines` and changing command-line flag(s) from `-e` to `-ne`:

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.raku.put;' sonnet18.txt
"Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?"
"Thou art more lovely and more temperate:"
"Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,"
"And summer’s lease hath all too short a date;"
"Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,"
"And often is his gold complexion dimm'd;"
"And every fair from fair sometime declines,"
"By chance or nature’s changing course untrimm'd;"
"But thy eternal summer shall not fade,"
"Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st;"
"Nor shall death brag thou wander’st in his shade,"
"When in eternal lines to time thou grow’st:"
"   So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,"
"   So long lives this, and this gives life to thee."
```

So the first question I have is whether `\n` newlines actually exist in your Raku text object(s). If so, you can double-escape them with the code as follows (adding `\` backslashes as required by your shell):

```perl
~$ raku -e 'put S:g/\n/\\\\n/ given slurp;' sonnet18.txt
Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?\\nThou art more lovely and more temperate:\\nRough winds do shake the darling buds of May,\\nAnd summer’s lease hath all too short a date;\\nSometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,\\nAnd often is his gold complexion dimm'd;\\nAnd every fair from fair sometime declines,\\nBy chance or nature’s changing course untrimm'd;\\nBut thy eternal summer shall not fade,\\nNor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st;\\nNor shall death brag thou wander’st in his shade,\\nWhen in eternal lines to time thou grow’st:\\n   So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,\\n   So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.\\n
```

OTOH, if you don't have true `\n` newlines in your Raku text object(s), you can simply append them (or any other text--such as `\\n`). Use `~` tilde for string concatenation, and add `\` backslashes as required by your shell:

```bash
~$ raku -e 'lines.map(* ~ "\\\\n").join.put;' sonnet18.txt
Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?\\nThou art more lovely and more temperate:\\nRough winds do shake the darling buds of May,\\nAnd summer’s lease hath all too short a date;\\nSometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,\\nAnd often is his gold complexion dimm'd;\\nAnd every fair from fair sometime declines,\\nBy chance or nature’s changing course untrimm'd;\\nBut thy eternal summer shall not fade,\\nNor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st;\\nNor shall death brag thou wander’st in his shade,\\nWhen in eternal lines to time thou grow’st:\\n   So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,\\n   So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.\\n

#OR (below gives same result as above--but without final \\n):

$ raku -e 'lines.join("\\\\n").put;' sonnet18.txt
Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?\\nThou art more lovely and more temperate:\\nRough winds do shake the darling buds of May,\\nAnd summer’s lease hath all too short a date;\\nSometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,\\nAnd often is his gold complexion dimm'd;\\nAnd every fair from fair sometime declines,\\nBy chance or nature’s changing course untrimm'd;\\nBut thy eternal summer shall not fade,\\nNor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st;\\nNor shall death brag thou wander’st in his shade,\\nWhen in eternal lines to time thou grow’st:\\n   So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,\\n   So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.
```

Finally, I have to put this here just in case someone has the far-more-common, opposite issue:  having to remove/correct `\\n` embedded characters from a text file. Using Raku:

```bash
~$ cat double_esc18.txt
Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?\\nThou art more lovely and more temperate:\\nRough winds do shake the darling buds of May,\\nAnd summer’s lease hath all too short a date;\\nSometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,\\nAnd often is his gold complexion dimm'd;\\nAnd every fair from fair sometime declines,\\nBy chance or nature’s changing course untrimm'd;\\nBut thy eternal summer shall not fade,\\nNor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st;\\nNor shall death brag thou wander’st in his shade,\\nWhen in eternal lines to time thou grow’st:\\n   So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,\\n   So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.\\n
~$ raku -pe 's:g/\\\\n/\n/;' double_esc18.txt
Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?
Thou art more lovely and more temperate:
Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
And summer’s lease hath all too short a date;
Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,
And often is his gold complexion dimm'd;
And every fair from fair sometime declines,
By chance or nature’s changing course untrimm'd;
But thy eternal summer shall not fade,
Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st;
Nor shall death brag thou wander’st in his shade,
When in eternal lines to time thou grow’st:
   So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,
   So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.
```